# How do I save the UI of a new instanced window when it closes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I have this project with two windows.

MainWindow and SecondaryWindow & I have a button on the MainWindow that initializes a new instance of the SecondaryWindow & opens it.

```
SecondaryWindow sw = new SecondaryWindow();
sw.Show();
```

The issue is.. When I check a checkbox on the SecondaryWindow and then close it, it clears the window when I open it again. I know why because it's opening a *NEW* isntance of the window everytime.
How do I make it save?

I tried doing this..

```
public static SecondaryWindow instance;
public SecondaryWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            instance = this;
        }
```

And then this in the MainWindow

```
SecondaryWindow sw;
```

And then doing this..

```
sw.Show();
```

but that line throws an error saying that it's null

I think thats called singleton what I was trying to do.

Comment: It is really hard to understand what are you want to achive, but I'll try. Maybe you do not need to save window, you just need to save some values and apply these values to the window when you open it again. Am I right?

Comment: Can you explain what you thought would happen when you created that static field? Can you walk through the reasoning process where you concluded that it would do something useful?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the value of the check box to a global variable. You can read or write into a global variable like this

```
App.Current.Properties["NameOfProperty"] = "ValueOfProperty";
string myProperty = App.Current.Properties["NameOfProperty"];
```

Like this, you can persist the value of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the `Show()` method of a window that has already been closed once.

What you could do is to create a view model class that keeps track of the value of the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox`, set the `DataContext` of `SecondaryWindow` to an instance of this class and bind the `CheckBox` in the view to the source property, e.g.:

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel _vm = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecondaryWindow sw = new SecondaryWindow();
        sw.DataContext = _vm;
        sw.Show();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

**SecondaryWindow.xaml:**

```
<CheckBox Content="Check" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
```